# Random forest with categorical dependent variables

Tags: r, random-forest

I am trying to run `randomForest` package with few dependent and few independent variables. Can anyone please let me know if it is at all possible to use a categorical variable (which has values like "AAA", "HCC1", "HCC2" etc) as the dependent variable for `randomForest` package?
Please note I am not talking about `cforest` package. 
For the issue above I heard that I need to convert the categorical variables to factors. But when I check with Class, the variable is shown as factor. When I am running the following syntax:

```
fit <- randomForest(Bkt_DerivedVariable1+Bkt_DerivedVariable4+hcc_trans_2013_col1 ~ Bkt_TopSecondaryDiagnosis1_2+Bkt_TopPrimaryDiagnosis3,data=testdata1)
```

The error is:

```
Error in na.fail.default(list(`Bkt_DerivedVariable1 + Bkt_DerivedVariable4 + Bkt_TopSecondaryDiagnosis1_1` = c(NA,  : 
  missing values in object
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(Bkt_DerivedVariable1 + Bkt_DerivedVariable4, Bkt_TopSecondaryDiagnosis1_1) :
  + not meaningful for factors
```

I am sure this is coming for the `hcc_trans_2013_col1` variable which has the above string values.

Can someone please tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that there are `missing values in object`.
So, before applying `randomForest()`, try this:

```
library(randomForest)
testdata1 <- na.roughfix(testdata1)  # for imputing the missing values in the data
```

and then:

```
fit <- randomForest(Bkt_DerivedVariable1+Bkt_DerivedVariable4+hcc_trans_2013_col1 ~ Bkt_TopSecondaryDiagnosis1_2+Bkt_TopPrimaryDiagnosis3,data=testdata1)
```

If the problem is with the missing values, then this should help.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. But I am assuring that there is no missing value present in the dependent variable. This is happening because of the character string. I tried to use other dependent variable which are numeric, the RF runs fine. Hence I would like to know how to use dependent variable with character string in Random Forest.

Comment: okay... then please check if the dependent variable with character string is of class `factor` or not (`is.factor(testdata1$your_coulumn_name)`). If not a factor, then convert it into factor and try RF again (`testdata1$your_coulumn_name <- as.factor(testdata1$your_coulumn_name)`).

Comment: Hi. Thanks again. Yes I have checked that the dependent variable is present as factor. I used is.factor(var name). It says TRUE. Hence this confuses me more as I already have the dependent variable as factor and only because this contains discrete character string, I can not use RF. I would really appreciate if any solution will come

Comment: You should give some reproducible data along with the question so that others could run the code on it. Please edit the question providing what kind of data you are dealing with.